# What instruction in the code segment helps to access variables from other segments?

Tags: c, memory

To increment the value of a variable by `1` we can write `variable_name++` in our source code.

But after compiling it the variable will be stored in data segment if it's initialized not to `0` and is global.

And the instruction to increment it by `1` will be stored in the code segment.

So what will be the another instruction in the code segment to access that variable before the instruction to increment it?

Comment: It's more about how it is *addressed*. Open your favorite architecture ISA and see.

Comment: You can paste the code on https://gcc.godbolt.org/ and browse through the different compilers and architectures in the dropdown menu to see what they do.